# Smarty: Correct Array Missing Keys

Tags: php, arrays, smarty, multidimensional-array

I'm calling an API via PHP that returns a multi-dimensional array [**$myArray**].

I want to pass this array for use in my Smarty template but for some reason the array is returning without the first dimension keys.

When I print_r on **$myArray** in PHP I get:

```
Array ( 
   [success] => 1 
   [errors] => 0 
   [data] => Array ( 
       [0] => Array ( 
                [email] => myemail@email.com
                [id] => hhd77sjr
                [timestamp] => 2011-08-10 16:31:29 
       ) 
   ) 
)
```

I assign this array as:
`$smarty->assign('my_array',$myArray);`

Then when I access **my_array** in my Smarty template via `{$my_array|print_r}` I get:

```
1
0
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
       [email] => myemail@email.com
       [id] => hhd77sjr
       [timestamp] => 2011-08-10 16:31:29
    )
)
```

What happened to my keys for the [success], [errors] and [data] values?  I'm only seeing the values. How can I access those values via something like: `{$my_array.success}` ?

THANKS for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

If you had been looked up on google searching for "smarty array", you could found this:

```
<ul>
{foreach from=$myArray key=k item=v}
   <li>{$k}: {$v}</li>
{/foreach}
</ul>
```

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach

Answer (score 0):

Without looking into the source, I'm guessing it has to do with how Smarty displays the result of `print_r()`. By default print_r tries to output directly, but looking at the PHP documentation:

> If you would like to capture the output of print_r(), use the return parameter. When this parameter is set to TRUE, print_r() will return the information rather than print it.

[Source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

You certainly should be able to access all the values normally, ie, `{$my_array.success}`.

If you'd like to try `print_r` again, try this: `{$my_array|print_r:true}` (set the return parameter to true).